# JavaMail: How to use different SOCKS5 for different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail, socks

I wrote multithreading application which connects to some email accounts from database per thread.
I know that JavaMail have no any options to use SOCKS5 for connection so I decided to use it via System.setProperty method. But this method sets SOCKS5 for whole application and I need to use one SOCKS5 per thread. I mean:

- first thread: uses SOCKS 192.168.0.1:12345 for bob@localhost to
  connect
- second thread: uses SOCKS 192.168.0.20:12312 for
  alice@localhost to connect
- third thread: uses SOCKS 192.168.12.:8080
  for andrew@localdomain to connect

and so on. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own socket using the Proxy you want:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("socks.mydomain.com", 1080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress("smtp.foo.com", 25);
socket.connect(dest);
```

Then use it for the connection:

```
SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(socket);
```

**Edit:** The tricky bit is if you need authentication with the SMTP server to send mail. If that's the case, you have to create a subclass of `javax.mail.Authenticator` and pass it to the `Session.getInstance()` method:

```
MyAuthenticator authenticator = new MyAuthenticator();

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter",
                        authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
```

Where the authenticator looks like:

```
private class MyAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{
    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator() 
    {
         String username = "auth-user";
         String password = "auth-password";
         authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
    {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

This is all untested, but I believe it's everything you have to do. It should at least put you on the right path.

Comment: Big thanks you are my potentional saver! :) I'll try it, thanks again!

Comment: Checked, Transport.connect has no implementation for Socket :(

Comment: Gah, sorry - `SMTPTransport` does.

Comment: And in dest variable I need to setup smtp host/smtp port? And with setuped smtp I shouldn't setup it in Properties for JavaMail?

Comment: Correct, the `dest` is your smtp server and port. You don't use properties in this case. The tricky bit is if you require authentication, because you'll have to manage that yourself. Trying to find a good reference, I've not done it in ages

Comment: Okay if I use SMTPTransport JavaMail can't connect to server (infinite connection) and debug shows that while Ctrl+C not pressed: http://pastebin.com/Mi1MYPJd So SMTPSSLTransport is need to be used or what? If yes there is exception happens: "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport"

Comment: Proxying SSL gets a bit more complicated. I'd have to research it.

Comment: Can you give me your contact please? :)

Comment: Also I discovered that if socket not use proxy it can't connect to (infinite connection happens). So the problem is in socket I think?