# Java Mail: How to use SOCKS for IMAP processing without global sytem properties?

Tags: java, proxy, imap, jakarta-mail, socks

I have the problem described in this question
[JavaMail: How to use different SOCKS5 for different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540976/javamail-how-to-use-different-socks5-for-different-threads/8035375#8035375)

..but there is no really answer to this question :-(

additionally I want to retrieve mails from an imap(s) folder and I don't know how to tell javaMail to use a socks proxy without setting via global system properties. (sockProxyHost and so on...)
If I do so parallel database requests also want to use the socks proxy but they shouldn't  (db is not accessible via socks proxy)

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint.
Hans

Comment: any hints? a copy of the system props doesn't help :-( is there another way than manipulating javaMail.jar?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it together with a colleague

to use a socks proxy you have to do the following..

inside the mail.jar you can find the SocketFetcher class. within this class it is checked if a session factory object or class name is set via system properties. I implemented my own SocketFactory copying from SSLSocketFactory and I had to manipulate the SocketFetcher inside javaMail and I replaced the class file to call createSocket(host, port) method from my own SocketFactory. And there I used a proxy to

```
String proxyHost = System.getProperty(SYSTEM_PROP_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST);
int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(SYSTEM_PROP_SOCKS_PROXY_PORT));

SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
socket = new Socket(proxy);
```

additionally I had to manipulate SocketFetcher.createSocket()
...

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

...you have to check if the socket is already connected otherwise an exception will be thrown and the default socketFactory will be used which isn't yours

Lots of luck :-)

Comment: Can you share fixed JavaMail version? And you still need to setup system properties?